# How to change the colour of geometry material in SceneKit

Tags: swift, swiftui, scenekit

I have the following code

```
let planeGeometry = SCNPlane(width: 5, height: 3)
let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: planeGeometry)
planeGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = Color(.blue)
planeGeometry.firstMaterial?.isDoubleSided = true
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(planeNode)
```

I tried applying colours in different ways like

```
let node = SCNNode()
let geometry = SCNBox(width: 3.0, height: 1, length: 1, chamferRadius: 0)
geometry.firstMaterial?.emission.contents = Color(hue: 10, saturation: 50, brightness: 10)      
node.geometry = geometry;
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
```

in an otherwise empty SceneKit project

it appears white no matter what

[image: white object]

I'm following a tutorial which suggests that this is supposed to produce an identical result to building out the scene in the visual editor. However things appear as I would expect in the visual editor

[image]

Comment: You are not applying it to your object.  Show all relevant lines of code.

Comment: Set the right tags.

Comment: thanks for responding. what do you mean by set the right tags?

Comment: The way you set a color to a side of a material suggests that the main framework you are using is SwiftUI, which you should add to your army of tags.

Comment: Oh I see. thank you. I added it. also added the rest of the relevant code

Comment: A `SCNBox` objects has 5 sides, which means that you need an array of five materials.

Comment: It should be something like the following, I suppose.  let material1 = SCNMaterial();
let material2 = SCNMaterial();
let material3 = SCNMaterial();
let material4 = SCNMaterial();
let material5 = SCNMaterial();
material1.diffuse.contents = Color(.blue);
material2.diffuse.contents = Color(.blue);
material3.diffuse.contents = Color(.blue);
material4.diffuse.contents = Color(.blue);
material5.diffuse.contents = Color(.blue);
geometry = [material1, material2, material3, material4, material5]

Comment: I tried that just now. it still appears plain white. Also tried a plane with 2 materials. I tried using an image instead of a colour. Still no luck.

Comment: If it's all white, then you probably have a wrong light source.  I'm not a career SKScene guy.  So that's all you get from me.

Comment: Where do you have your light source and what is the `LightType` of your light node?  Isn't it probably set to `Directional` or `Ambient`?

Comment: I was using the enable global illumination tag on the view. But I the problem went away when I added an a burnt light to the parent node. Thanks for your help. I tried it based on your suggestion

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but you are using the emission material property within your code, and you use values greater than 1.0 to configure the color. I thin the values for configuring a HUE Color Material mut not be greater than 1.0 for each value. The values might be jut too high and you object appears white. Is your color class of type UIColor? (Which lightingModel do you use? physicallyBased? Blinn?)

Answer (score 2):

The issue was that I didn’t have lighting. When I added ambient light to the parent node the colours started changing. I didn’t think I needed to because I had the default lighting flag enabled for the scene